# How do I add a prefix when a user registers

Tags: plugin-development, user-registration

I am looking for any built in function that when I add a user or a user wants to register, the username will be automatically prepended with a predefined text.

For example, if the user registers with `abul`, the username will be saved as `tk_abul`.

Comment: how do you save the user?

Comment: I want to add user from WordPress dashboard

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre_user_login` filter to customize username when registered. Example.

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'wpse_customize_user' );

function wpse_customize_user( $username ) {
    return 'tk_' . $username;
}
```

Comment: This is working but it is returning double tk after register. ex: tk_tk_username

Answer (score 0):

Try [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook. The following code wasn't tested.

```
<?php
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_nickname_prepend_function' );

function my_nickname_prepend_function( $user_id )
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', 'tk_' . $_POST['user_login'] );
    }
}
```

Remember about user input validation.

[Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is at your service.